# using docker with nvidia

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-touch

while trying to use UBports [clickable](https://clickable-ut.dev/en/latest/commands.html#clickable-desktop-nvidia) with docker I got the following:

```
LANG=C sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-compute-440
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-compute-440
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 152 not upgraded.
86 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/20.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 107 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 293169 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-compute-440_440.82-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-440:amd64 (440.82-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-440_440.82-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so', which is also in package nvidia-340 340.108-0ubuntu0.19.10.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-440_440.82-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

clickable call:

```
sudo clickable --verbose desktop
Clickable v6.14.0
Architecture set to "all" because builder "pure" is architecture agnostic
Nvidia driver detected, turning on nvidia mode.
App config value clickable_minimum_required: 6.12.2
App config value arch: all
App config value restrict_arch_env: None
App config value restrict_arch: None
App config value arch_triplet: all
App config value template: None
App config value builder: pure
App config value postmake: None
App config value prebuild: None
App config value build: None
App config value postbuild: None
App config value launch: None
App config value build_dir: /home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app
App config value build_home: /home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/.clickable/home
App config value src_dir: /home/abd/Projects/UT/html5
App config value root_dir: /home/abd/Projects/UT/html5
App config value kill: webapp-container*
App config value scripts: {}
App config value default: clean build install launch
App config value log: None
App config value dependencies_build: []
App config value dependencies_host: []
App config value dependencies_target: []
App config value dependencies_ppa: []
App config value install_lib: []
App config value install_bin: []
App config value install_qml: []
App config value install_data: {}
App config value app_lib_dir: /home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib
App config value app_bin_dir: /home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install
App config value app_qml_dir: /home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/qml
App config value ignore: ['.git', '.bzr', '.clickable']
App config value make_jobs: 0
App config value gopath: None
App config value cargo_home: /root/.clickable/cargo
App config value docker_image: clickable/ubuntu-sdk:16.04-amd64-nvidia
App config value build_args: []
App config value env_vars: {}
App config value make_args: ['-j2']
App config value dirty: False
App config value libraries: {}
App config value test: qmltestrunner
App config value install_dir: /home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install
App config value image_setup: {}
Running the "desktop" command
Using docker container "clickable/ubuntu-sdk:16.04-amd64-nvidia"
Copied files to install directory for click building
Successfully built package in './html5.yourname_1.0.0_all.click'.
Click outputted to /home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/html5.yourname_1.0.0_all.click
non-network local connections being added to access control list
Mounting device home to /root/.clickable/home
Too many arguments.
docker run --privileged --net=host -v /home/abd/Projects/UT/html5:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5:Z -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:Z -v /tmp/.docker.xauth:/tmp/.docker.xauth:Z -v /root/.clickable/home:/home/phablet:Z -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:Z -v /dev/snd/pcmC2D0c:/dev/snd/pcmC2D0c:Z -v /dev/snd/controlC2:/dev/snd/controlC2:Z -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm:Z -v /etc/machine-id:/etc/machine-id:Z -v /run/0/pulse:/run/user/1000/pulse:Z -v /var/lib/dbus:/var/lib/dbus:Z -v /home/root/.pulse:/home/phablet/.pulse:Z -v /dev/snd:/dev/snd:Z -e APP_ID=html5.yourname -e LANG=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LANGUAGE=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LC_CTYPE=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LC_NUMERIC=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LC_TIME=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LC_COLLATE=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LC_MONETARY=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LC_MESSAGES=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LC_PAPER=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LC_NAME=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LC_ADDRESS=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LC_TELEPHONE=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LC_MEASUREMENT=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LC_IDENTIFICATION=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e LC_ALL=ar_MA.UTF-8 -e TZ=Africa/Casablanca -e APP_DIR=/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install -e TEXTDOMAINDIR= -e XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.docker.xauth -e DISPLAY=:0 -e QML2_IMPORT_PATH=/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64 -e LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64 -e PATH=/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/bin:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bin:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/bin:/usr/bin -e HOME=/home/phablet -e OXIDE_NO_SANDBOX=1 -e UBUNTU_APP_LAUNCH_ARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu --device=/dev/snd --gpus=all -w /home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install --user=0 --rm -it clickable/ubuntu-sdk:16.04-amd64-nvidia bash -c "webapp-container --app-id="html5.yourname" $@ www/index.html"                                              
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"process_linux.go:432: running prestart hook 0 caused \\\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: detection error: nvml error: function not found\\\\n\\\"\"": unknown.
Command exited with an error:['docker', 'run', '--privileged', '--net=host', '-v', '/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5:Z', '-v', '/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:Z', '-v', '/tmp/.docker.xauth:/tmp/.docker.xauth:Z', '-v', '/root/.clickable/home:/home/phablet:Z', '-v', '/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:Z', '-v', '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0c:/dev/snd/pcmC2D0c:Z', '-v', '/dev/snd/controlC2:/dev/snd/controlC2:Z', '-v', '/dev/shm:/dev/shm:Z', '-v', '/etc/machine-id:/etc/machine-id:Z', '-v', '/run/0/pulse:/run/user/1000/pulse:Z', '-v', '/var/lib/dbus:/var/lib/dbus:Z', '-v', '/home/root/.pulse:/home/phablet/.pulse:Z', '-v', '/dev/snd:/dev/snd:Z', '-e', 'APP_ID=html5.yourname', '-e', 'LANG=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LANGUAGE=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_CTYPE=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_NUMERIC=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_TIME=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_COLLATE=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_MONETARY=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_MESSAGES=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_PAPER=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_NAME=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_ADDRESS=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_TELEPHONE=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_MEASUREMENT=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_IDENTIFICATION=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_ALL=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'TZ=Africa/Casablanca', '-e', 'APP_DIR=/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install', '-e', 'TEXTDOMAINDIR=', '-e', 'XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.docker.xauth', '-e', 'DISPLAY=:0', '-e', 'QML2_IMPORT_PATH=/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64', '-e', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64', '-e', 'PATH=/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/bin:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bin:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/bin:/usr/bin', '-e', 'HOME=/home/phablet', '-e', 'OXIDE_NO_SANDBOX=1', '-e', 'UBUNTU_APP_LAUNCH_ARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu', '--device=/dev/snd', '--gpus=all', '-w', '/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install', '--user=0', '--rm', '-it', 'clickable/ubuntu-sdk:16.04-amd64-nvidia', 'bash', '-c', 'webapp-container --app-id=html5.yourname $@ www/index.html']                                                                                                                    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/clickable/__init__.py", line 263, in main
    clickable.run(args.commands, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/clickable/__init__.py", line 247, in run
    cmd.run(command_arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/clickable/commands/desktop.py", line 41, in run
    self.run_app()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/clickable/commands/desktop.py", line 242, in run_app
    subprocess.check_call(shlex.split(command), cwd=docker_config.working_directory)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['docker', 'run', '--privileged', '--net=host', '-v', '/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5:Z', '-v', '/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:Z', '-v', '/tmp/.docker.xauth:/tmp/.docker.xauth:Z', '-v', '/root/.clickable/home:/home/phablet:Z', '-v', '/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:Z', '-v', '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0c:/dev/snd/pcmC2D0c:Z', '-v', '/dev/snd/controlC2:/dev/snd/controlC2:Z', '-v', '/dev/shm:/dev/shm:Z', '-v', '/etc/machine-id:/etc/machine-id:Z', '-v', '/run/0/pulse:/run/user/1000/pulse:Z', '-v', '/var/lib/dbus:/var/lib/dbus:Z', '-v', '/home/root/.pulse:/home/phablet/.pulse:Z', '-v', '/dev/snd:/dev/snd:Z', '-e', 'APP_ID=html5.yourname', '-e', 'LANG=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LANGUAGE=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_CTYPE=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_NUMERIC=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_TIME=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_COLLATE=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_MONETARY=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_MESSAGES=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_PAPER=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_NAME=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_ADDRESS=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_TELEPHONE=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_MEASUREMENT=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_IDENTIFICATION=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'LC_ALL=ar_MA.UTF-8', '-e', 'TZ=Africa/Casablanca', '-e', 'APP_DIR=/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install', '-e', 'TEXTDOMAINDIR=', '-e', 'XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.docker.xauth', '-e', 'DISPLAY=:0', '-e', 'QML2_IMPORT_PATH=/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64', '-e', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64', '-e', 'PATH=/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/bin:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bin:/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/bin:/usr/bin', '-e', 'HOME=/home/phablet', '-e', 'OXIDE_NO_SANDBOX=1', '-e', 'UBUNTU_APP_LAUNCH_ARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu', '--device=/dev/snd', '--gpus=all', '-w', '/home/abd/Projects/UT/html5/build/all/app/install', '--user=0', '--rm', '-it', 'clickable/ubuntu-sdk:16.04-amd64-nvidia', 'bash', '-c', 'webapp-container --app-id=html5.yourname $@ www/index.html']' returned non-zero exit status 125.
Command exited with non-zero exit status 125, see above for details. This is most likely not a problem with Clickable.


dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
iU  libaccinj64-10.1:amd64                        10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA ACCINJ Library (64-bit)
iU  libcublas10:amd64                             10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA cuBLAS Library
iU  libcublaslt10:amd64                           10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA cuBLASLt Library
iU  libcudart10.1:amd64                           10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA CUDA Runtime Library
iU  libcufft10:amd64                              10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA cuFFT Library
iU  libcufftw10:amd64                             10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA cuFFTW Library
iU  libcuinj64-10.1:amd64                         10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA CUINJ Library (64-bit)
iU  libcurand10:amd64                             10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA cuRAND Library
iU  libcusolver10:amd64                           10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA cuSOLVER Library
iU  libcusparse10:amd64                           10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA cuSPARSE Library
iU  libnppc10:amd64                               10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives core runtime library
iU  libnppial10:amd64                             10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Arithmetic and Logic
iU  libnppicc10:amd64                             10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Color Conversion
iU  libnppicom10:amd64                            10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Compression
iU  libnppidei10:amd64                            10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Data Exchange and Initialization
iU  libnppif10:amd64                              10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Filters
iU  libnppig10:amd64                              10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Geometry transforms
iU  libnppim10:amd64                              10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Morphological operations
iU  libnppist10:amd64                             10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Statistics
iU  libnppisu10:amd64                             10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Support
iU  libnppitc10:amd64                             10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Threshold and Compare
iU  libnpps10:amd64                               10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives for signal processing runtime library
iU  libnvgraph10:amd64                            10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Graph Analytics library (nvGRAPH)
ic  libnvidia-compute-440:amd64                   440.82-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-container-tools                     1.1.1-1                                amd64        NVIDIA container runtime library (command-line tools)
ii  libnvidia-container1:amd64                    1.1.1-1                                amd64        NVIDIA container runtime library
iU  libnvjpeg10:amd64                             10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA JPEG library (nvJPEG)
iU  libnvrtc10.1:amd64                            10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        CUDA Runtime Compilation (NVIDIA NVRTC Library)
iU  libnvtoolsext1:amd64                          10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Tools Extension Library
iU  libnvvm3:amd64                                10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA NVVM Library
iU  nsight-compute                                10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Nsight Compute
iU  nsight-systems                                10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Nsight Systems
ii  nvidia-340                                    340.108-0ubuntu0.19.10.1               amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.108
ii  nvidia-container-toolkit                      1.1.1-1                                amd64        NVIDIA container runtime hook
iU  nvidia-cuda-dev                               10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development files
iU  nvidia-cuda-doc                               10.1.168-1build1                       all          NVIDIA CUDA and OpenCL documentation
iU  nvidia-cuda-gdb                               10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA CUDA Debugger (GDB)
iU  nvidia-cuda-toolkit                           10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development toolkit
iU  nvidia-opencl-dev:amd64                       10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL development files
rc  nvidia-opencl-icd-340                         340.108-0ubuntu0.19.10.1               amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
iU  nvidia-openjdk-8-jre                          9.+8u77~10.1.168-1build1               amd64        NVIDIA provided OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
iU  nvidia-profiler                               10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Profiler for CUDA and OpenCL
ii  nvidia-settings                               440.64-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
iU  nvidia-visual-profiler                        10.1.168-1build1                       amd64        NVIDIA Visual Profiler for CUDA and OpenCL
ii  screen-resolution-extra                       0.18                                   all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
```

Comment: I think you are trying to install two different versions of Nvidia driver (440 and 340) hence the error : 
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so', which is also in package nvidia-340 340.108-0ubuntu0.19.10.1"

Comment: And in the clickable output , I don't see any errors.

Comment: @Parsa Mousavi I installed 440 which didn't work and the recent is 340 which loads fine.

unsure if remains something related to **440** causing the issue!

Comment: So you have to delete the 440 completely before installing the 340

Comment: Please use `LANG=C` before the commands and edit your question with the English output

Comment: And add your user to the `docker` group, and avoid running clickable with `sudo` as it's not necessary.